# Bokeh: Why do I need to call the source.change.emit() to update the location of a Span?

Tags: python, bokeh

I want to highlight the sample over which I´m hovering. I did managed to solve this with a custom JSCallback. See the minimal working example below.
My question is, why do I need to call `source.change.emit()` in order to update the location of my Span? If I remove the `source.change.emit()` in my callback, the location of the horizontal line does not change at all (visually). So far I thought, I only need to call this command, if I actually change the data inside the source object (like `source.data['Value1'] = <new_value>`.

```
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.plotting import figure, curdoc
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, HoverTool, CustomJS, Span
from bokeh.layouts import layout

plot1 = figure(plot_width=1000, plot_height=250)

df = pd.DataFrame({"ID":[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], 
                   "Value1":[0, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700], 
                   "Value2":[0, 1, 2, 4,8 , 16, 32, 64]})
source = ColumnDataSource(df)

line = plot1.line(x='ID', y='Value1', source=source)
circle = plot1.circle(x='ID', y='Value1', source=source)

v_line = Span(location=2,  dimension='height', line_color='green',
                              line_dash='dashed', line_width=3)
plot1.add_layout(v_line)

callback = CustomJS(args=dict(source=source, v_line=v_line), 
                        code="""
                        v_line.location = cb_data['index'].line_indices[0];
                        source.change.emit();
                        """)

hover_tool_plot = HoverTool(mode='vline', line_policy='nearest', callback=callback, renderers=[line])

plot1.add_tools(hover_tool_plot)

layout_ = layout([[plot1]])
curdoc().add_root(layout_)
```

In my application, I deal with a lot of data in multiple plots having the same source object. So when I include the `source.change.emit()` part in the callback the Span loacation changes, but the visual hover annoation gets noticeably slower and also skips some samples because of this non-smoothness.  Is there a way to update the location of the Span without calling `source.change.emit()`?
Thanks in advance.

Edit:
I'm running on Bokeh 2.3.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you move outside the begin/end of the line, the `location` then `line_indices` is empty, and setting from `line_indices[0]` is undefined. In this case things stop updating because `undefined` is not a valid thing to set `location` to. Perhaps this is what you are seeing?

This version of the code updates and keeps the tooltip and span in sync without an `emit` call with Bokeh 2.3 (note: please always, *always* specify relevant software versions in *every* question)

```py
callback = CustomJS(args=dict(source=source, v_line=v_line),
                        code="""
                        const loc = cb_data['index'].line_indices[0]
                        if (loc === undefined) {
                             v_line.visible = false
                        } else {
                            v_line.visible = true
                            v_line.location = loc;
                        }
                        """)

hover_tool_plot = HoverTool(mode='vline', line_policy='prev', 
                            callback=callback, renderers=[line])
```

Note I have also changed `line_policy` to `prev` because I believe that is what `line_indices` will always report, regardless. It's possible this could be made more flexible, but no one has ever asked about it before. Feel free to propose a feature request [on github](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues).

Comment: Thanks so much! I did not know, that once a property is set to `undefined`, it completely stops updating. This is a very important thing to know in my opinion.  
Additionally I found, that the same seems true when trying to set a value of `Infinity` to the `.location` (which in my case sometimes happened when using `cb_data['geometry'].x` in the callback).

Comment: Well, it almost certainly depends on the specific property as to whether setting undefined is a recoverable error or not. But it falls under "undefined behavior" regardless, so should be avoided. In general, Bokeh model properties are all strictly typed (with the types documented in the reference guide) and only values with those types are valid.